# GoogleAppEngine Java Application deployment

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I built a sample Java application on Google App Engine and now when I am deploying it using the command `appcfg.cmd -A summer-hawk-102105 update target /appengine/`, it's giving an error:

> unable to find the webapp directory target\appengine/

Comment: You need to provide the path to the `war` you are uploading. The [update command](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp) is `appcfg.cmd [options] update <war-location>`.  This error suggests there is no `WEB-INF` directory inside your `target/appengine` directory.

Comment: sir can you please tell me about the war .Is it the demo servelet because i have a WEBINF directory in appengine folder.

Comment: The `war` directory is the bundle that gets deployed to App Engine, containing `WEB-INF`... but I just noticed the question is tagged *maven*, so you can just run `mvn appengine:update` instead.

Comment: Thank you but I can give you the address of the WEB-INF directory "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\appengine-try-java-master\target\appengine-try-java-1.0\WEB-INF" .I just ran the  appcfg command by coming to this directory but it is not able to find the path to webapp directory.